# PHP function reference to another function

Tags: php, function, phpunit

Is it at all possible to do this in PHP: (Solved: Yes it is possible to do this.)

```
/// Unit test for class some below
class some_test{
  function test_foo1 () {

      $var->fileName = "name";
      $var->fileLocation = "Location";
      $var->fileType = "png"; 
      $var->someFunction() = foo2();
      // Do $var->someFunction = foo2();

    }

    function foo2() {
      ....do something ....
    }
}

// Class Under test
class some {
      function foo1(){
        $var = getObjWith_someFunction();
        if(isset($var))
           $var->someFunction();
      }
    }
```

I need to do this because when I am writing this unit test for a class where someFunction() is being called, it says that the someFunction() does not exist. So I need to create a dummy function in the test case.

```
  Code example:

   class pictureManager {

    public function getPicture() {
       try {
         $picObj = getPicObj(1); 
       }
       catch (Exception) {
         if (isset($picObj)) $picObj->showMessage();
       }
     }

     public function getPicObj($id){ // Need to mock this function to return picClass object
       return new picClass($id);
     }
   }

   class picClass {
     public $id;
     public function __construct($id){
       $this->id = id;
     }

     public function showMessage(){
       echo "in this function";
     }
   }

   Unit Test for class pictureManager:

   class pictureManager_test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

     public function test_getPicture() {

        $fixture = $this->getMock('pictureManager', array('getPicObj'));
        $arg = 1;

        // Here I am creating the return obj on the fly. Can this be done? (Yes)
        $returnValue->id = 1; 
>>>     $returnValue->showMessage() = someThing();  // This is where I am stuck

//Solution: $returnValue->showMessage = someThing();   
//Remove the brackets (). Since I cant answer my question I am writing it here.

        $fixture::staticExpects($this->once())
                           ->method('getPicObj')
                           ->with($arg)
                           ->will($this->returnValue($returnValue));
        $fixture->getPicture(); 
     }

   }
```

Comment: [from the php manual](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)  not available until php 5.3

Comment: Is it possible to do what? Where is `someFunction()` defined? Also, you're checking `isset($var)` immediately after you set `$var`. Can't you imply that it's always going to be set? Were you looking for `!empty()` or `!is_null()` perhaps?

Comment: please add code demonstrating how you want to use these classes.

Comment: I want to create `someFunction()` on the fly. Is it not possible in PHP? `getObjWith_someFunction()` will return an object of a class which has 3 member variables `fileName`, `fileLocation`, `fileType` and one member function `someFunction()`. If `getObjWith_someFunction()` does returns the correct object, `someFunction()` would be called. I will write some more code to make it clear.

Comment: Your code isn't correct, you don't instantiate `$returnValue`. Furthermore I see no class containing the fields `fileName`, `fileLocation` or `fileType`. And then your question: you want to replace the method showMessage for one instance of that class (i.e. one object) by a new function, called `someThing()`?

Comment: @CodeCaster I corrected my code. There is only $id. Furthermore I need to mock the call to function `getPicObj` but need to return an object of class `picClass`. This where my confusion is. I cant create an object in my unit test code so I must do something to return some object with the member function with the same name as well.

Comment: @Sumitk I don't really understand, but perhaps using and implementing interfaces will work, given the "object with the member function with the same name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP 5.3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) is the first version to accept this, so yes it is possible.

But if you are on any previous version, you will need to use the [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) function.

5.3 also allows dynamic creation of functions in a way [similar to lambda functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#PHP).

Here's a sum-up:

```
// Obvious
function a() {
  // do something
}

$b = a; // this works in PHP 5.3+

$c = create_function('$someArgs', 'return $someArgs;'); // PHP 4.0.1+

$d = function() { /* do something else */ }; // PHP 5.3+
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt. I really thought it was possible. But when I am doing this: `$var->someFoo() = function () { return null; }` its giving me `HP Fatal error:  Can't use method return value in write context`

Comment: ohh got it. Instead of doing this: 
`>>>     $returnValue->showMessage() = someThing();  `
I only needed to do this:
`>>>     $returnValue->showMessage = someThing();`
I should have tried that before.